# How to suppress the 5 hindrance to achieve the first jhana?

Tags: jhana

I am reading books on the subject. But don't fully understand the language as im new to meditation and Buddhism. I want to learn the jhanas one at a time to work my way up. But im lost when it comes to getting rid of the 5 hindrances. I dont quiet get how to do t. Any tips.. I wish i could find a teahcer but i have no money to travel and theres no one here in my location.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

'Suppressing' the five hindrances is not the method of the Pali suttas.

In the Pali suttas, the five hindrances are 'abandoned', 'purified' or 'cleansed' using wisdom, as explained in [MN 19](https://suttacentral.net/en/mn19), [MN 20](https://suttacentral.net/en/mn20), [DN 13](https://suttacentral.net/en/dn13), [SN 46.55](http://www.accesstoinsight.org/tipitaka/sn/sn46/sn46.055.wlsh.html), etc.

> *Abandoning covetousness with regard to the world, he dwells with an awareness devoid of covetousness. He cleanses his mind of
>   covetousness. Abandoning ill will & anger, he dwells with an awareness
>   devoid of ill will, sympathetic with the welfare of all living beings.
>   He cleanses his mind of ill will & anger. Abandoning sloth &
>   drowsiness, he dwells with an awareness devoid of sloth & drowsiness,
>   mindful, alert, percipient of light. He cleanses his mind of sloth &
>   drowsiness. Abandoning restlessness & anxiety, he dwells undisturbed,
>   his mind inwardly stilled. He cleanses his mind of restlessness &
>   anxiety. Abandoning uncertainty, he dwells having crossed over
>   uncertainty, with no perplexity with regard to skillful mental
>   qualities. He cleanses his mind of uncertainty.*
>
> *Having abandoned these five hindrances — imperfections of awareness that weaken wisdom — then, quite secluded from sensuality,
>   secluded from unskillful qualities, he enters and remains in the first
>   jhāna: rapture & pleasure born of seclusion, accompanied by directed
>   thought & evaluation.*
>
> [MN 38](http://www.accesstoinsight.org/tipitaka/mn/mn.038.than.html)

Comment: Okay now the books are making a Bit more sense. So i need to change my life to abandon the unwholesome hindrances?

Comment: Basically, I would say yes. Even after changing life, it takes a far bit of time to develop the (real) jhanas. Regards

Answer (score 1):

Jhana and abandoning the 5 hindrances are interrelated, but abandoning the 5 hindrances alone will not get Jhana. The main things to get to the 1st Jhana is [vitakka](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vitarka) & [vicāra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vicara). You have to establish your mind on an object and then apply sustainable effort to retain your mind on the object. It is though this effort that the 1st Jhana arises. For a slightly more detailed discussion see [this answer](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/a/19630/295).